# change the background color based on the position of the elements dynamically

Tags: css

I have three simple div in my webpage

```
<div class="box">
    DIV A
</div>
<div class="box">
    DIV B
</div>
<div class="box">
    DIV C
</div>
```

I would like to know if it is possible (using only css) assigning to 3 (or more) div (with same class selector) a background color by setting a start color  and then change the saturation from time to time until the last div.

What I am doing now is setting for each div the `background-color` property but these elements are generated dinamically and I don't know how many they are.

Image example of what I would reach.

[image]

setting somethink like

```
.box{
   background-color:#123456;
}
```

and

```
.box:nth-child(n){
   background-color-add:#000001;
}
```

in this way background-color of `n`-th element will be always different from `n+1`-th background.

My question is : 

Is it possible?
 if yes how?

Comment: This is not possible with pure css. Can you change to less/sass as they have many color functions.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/G5RP3/3/) Do you mean this alternative colors?? or different colors

Comment: @user3168736 differents for every box not only for n+1, n+3 etc

Comment: I dont find only CSS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do just with css and if you don't want to use anything like sass or less and or jquery then just consider first how many of maximum div you may have and define the color for each boxes:

```
.box:nth-child(1){
   background-color:#000001;
}
.box:nth-child(2){
   background-color:#000011;
}
.box:nth-child(3){
   background-color:#000111;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I am doing now. If it's not possible I will accept this answer